# Black detect ffmpeg and use in a javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I had an ffmpeg script that allow me to detect black frames from a video file sample from the bottom.

and i want to create a javascript code that will allow me to do the same function sample from the bottom but its not working.

original code from ffmpeg script:

`ffmpeg -i LKE-BLACK.mp4 -vf "blackdetect=d=0.5:pix_th=0.10" -an -f null - 2>&1 | findstr blackdetect > output.txt

node script:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const ffmpeg = require("ffmpeg.js");

var createStream = fs.createWriteStream("data.txt");
createStream.end();

const transcode = async ({ target: { files }  }) => {
    message.innerHTML = 'Loading ffmpeg-core.js';
    await ffmpeg.load();
    message.innerHTML = 'Start transcoding';
    
    await ffmpeg.transcode('-i', 'LKE-BLACK.mp4', "-vf", "blackdetect=d=0.5:pix_th=0.10", '-an', '-f', 'null - 2>&1', );
    message.innerHTML = 'Complete transcoding';

    fs.writeFile("data.txt", function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('File is created successfully.');
      });
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] add some information what did you try to do. Add some more information and create [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I did find answer but not using javascript instead i use pyton for this problem o be solved